# ServiceLocator GetAllInstances does not contain instance whose contract name is specified

Tags: c#, mef, service-locator, common-service-locator

Suppose I have an interface `ITest`:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void PrintMachineInfo();
}
```

And plus two implementations:

```
[Export("MachineName", typeof(ITest))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Test1 : ITest
{
    public void PrintMachineInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.MachineName);
    }
}

[Export(typeof(ITest))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Test2 : ITest
{
    public void PrintMachineInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.OSVersion);
    }
}
```

Then, I tried to retrieve all instances of `ITest`:

```
var foo = ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<ITest>();
foreach (var test in foo)
{
    test.PrintMachineInfo();
}
```

It turns out that only instance of `Test2` can be returned. Because of the contract name, it just cannot find instance of `Test1`.

I use MEF + [ServiceLocator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/) + [MefAdapter](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator.MefAdapter/) to make all those stuff run. From my debugging, MefAdapter overwrite the method `DoGetAllInstances(Type serviceType)` in `ServiceLocatorImplBase`, but it only provide one parameter `serviceType`.

So, how can get all instances of `ITest` with ServiceLocator, regardless whehter the implementation has contact name exported or not?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to achieve what you want with current implementation of the `IServiceLocator` that is provided by Prism.

The overridden `DoGetAllInstances()` method in that implementation calls the last overload of the `GetExport()` method:

```
this.compositionContainer.GetExports(serviceType, null, null);
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833288(v=vs.110).aspx), the third argument is a

> ***contractName***: The contract name of the Lazy object to return, or **null** or an empty string ("") to use the default contract name.

As you can see in remarks to this topic:

> The default contract name is the result of calling the GetContractName
>   method on type.

That default contract name is based on the full type name, without any additional keys. That is why you get only the second export: it has the default contract name.

So, there is no way to get all the exports in that way without exactly knowing all the contract keys.

To provide multiple exports while being able to distinguish them, you could provide additional metadata to each export and leave same export contract names:

```
[Export(typeof(ITest))]
[ExportMetadata("Type", "MachineName")]
public class Test1 : ITest { }

[Export(typeof(ITest))]
[ExportMetadata("Type", string.Empty)]
public class Test2 : ITest { }
```